# How to clear selected value from dynamic select dropdown in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I have implemented a form in which a Select dropdown is taking dynamic data from server.

Now when I select a option from dropdown, it is showing value in the field, but after saving the form or cancel saving it, when I reopen the form, the selected value is not cleared from field.

What needs to be done to correct it?
Here is my code:

```
 class Task extends Component{
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
        SelectedName:'',
        TaskList:[],
       }
    }
  
 componentWillMount(){
 fetch(
 ...
   .then(responseJson => {
       let taskList=responseJson.data;
       let r = taskList.map(function(task){
            return {value: task.id, display: task.name}
          });
       this.setState({TaskList:r });
 }

//this is cancelForm fucntion
  cancelSave=()=>{
     this.setState({SelectedName:''});
   }

handleNameSelection=()=>{
 var row = this.state.TaskList.filter(function (item) {
            return item.value == event.target.value
         })
 this.setState({ SelectedName: row[0].display});
}

 render(){
   return(
    <Select
         defaultValue="placeholder-item"
         id="select-task-name"
         labelText="Select Task Name"
         value={this.state.SelectedName}
         onChange={(event) => this.handleNameSelection(event)}
       >
              {
                (this.state.TaskList.length > 0) ?
                  this.state.TaskList.map(function (list, idx) {
                    return <option key={idx}
                      value={list.value}>{list.display}</option>
                  })
                  :
                  <option />
              }
            </Select>

    );

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should empty  array list of tasks in the state after your form submit

here I can't see your submit function ( if you're using this above as subcomonent it's another logic to implement otherwise see below example )
as example :

```
let onSubmit = (values) => {
   /* form submit stuff */

   this.setState({
      ...state,
      SelectedName:''
   });

}
```

Comment: But @Sadhil, by doing `TaskList:[]` , the options are removed from dropdown as I have put the server data in TaskList in willComponentMount() method. I just need to clear the selected input from field, whenever I open the form again.

Comment: @unak okey  misunderstood the question , try updated , if doesn't work again tell me wich select component you're using (FrameWork)

Comment: Are you using bootstrap Select ?